# How to connect to HTTPS repository from Nexus OSS?

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, https, nexus

Could I use Sonatype Nexus OSS to connect to a SSL repository? 
(ex: https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/)

I find this document, only Nexus Pro supports to add SSL certificate on GUI.
(http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/ssl-sect-client-cert.html)

Therefore, I try to download the certificate from browser, use this command to import the key. But it still doesn't work. I use Tomcat 7.0 and JDK 1.7 64bit, is it possible to use HTTPS repository?

```
keytool -import -alias Cloudera -keystore D:\JDK\1.7.0_45_x64\jre\lib\security\cacerts -file d:\cloudera.txt -storepass changeit
```

Answer (score 1):

The certificate of the cloudera server has to be known to Nexus. In Nexus OSS you have to import it into the truststore of the JVM running Nexus. In Nexus Pro you can use the build in SSL configuration. More details are available in the [SSL chapter of the Nexus book](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/ssl.html).

Comment: Hi, I found the tool http://central.sonatype.com/help/import-ssl.jar is not available for download now, do you know where can I get it?

Comment: Thanks, does this tool only support PKCS#12 format? Because it seems .p12 contains private key and I think we cannot get private key of cloudera's website. I'm not familiar with security technology, is it correct?

Comment: Not sure. I would suggest to talk to support/the developers tomorrow on our hipchat channel. http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/participate

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.

Are you going through an http proxy server or firewall to reach the internet?  If so, it is very likely that this is decrypting SSL traffic and re-encrypting it with a certificate that is not considered valid by your JRE.

You'll need to get this certificate from your IT department and import it into the JRE truststore like you did with the Cloudera cerificate.

Comment: I'm behind a firewall, but I use Chrome (through firewall) to get the certificate. And does it mean I need to ask IT to get the original certificate? Like the certificate I download without a proxy or firewall?

Comment: I download a certificate and import it again, but still have the same error. Is there any suggestion?